# CConsoleApplication.defaultController not defined when creating new migration

Tags: yii, database-migration, yii-migrations

I'm trying to use the yii migration system but I'm stuck on this error when I execute this commande:

```
yiic migrate create add_table_test
```

I get this error:

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property   CConsoleApplication.defaultController" is not defined'
```

(CCompenent.php:173)

But I've defined a defaultController in my config file:

```
'basePath'=>$rootPath,
'defaultController' => 'person/index',
'homeUrl'=>array('/me'),
```

I spent hours looking on Google, but I can't find a solution.

Does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Comment: In which config file did you define it? your main config or the console config?

Comment: This guide might be useful: https://human.software/human-thoughts/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii-and-cconsolecommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you've actually defined the property `defaultController` in your `config/console.php` but as the error message says the `CConsoleApplication` has no such property.

So just remove `defaultController` from your console config.

Answer (score 2):

(*this is actually an answer given by OP (Michaël). I'm putting it here, because he put it into question)*

It turned out, that the problem was on my side. I did a really bad thing.

Problem was solved by:

1. Replacing in `yiic.php` line `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/dev.php';` with `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php';`.
2. Create a `console.php` file in the `config` directory, without `defaultController` and `theme` option.